# htaccess Rewriteurl Looping

Tags: .htaccess

I have problem when using `htaccess rewriteurl`, it was stacking every I change the page,

I try this one :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /test/category.php?k=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

**change this**

```
http://localhost/test/category.php?k=fashion&page=2
```

**become like this**

```
http://localhost/test/category/fashion/2
```

**the problem occure when i'm going to page 3**

URL become like this

```
http://localhost/test/category/fashion/category/fashion/3
```

so on...

switch page to page 4

```
http://localhost/test/category/fashion/category/fashion/category/fashion/3
```

why is this looping?

what's wrong with my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've changed your URL's to look like `http://localhost/test/category/fashion/2`, any relative links on that page will think the new URL base is: `http://localhost/test/category/fashion/` instead of `http://localhost/test/`, which would be the base if the browser loaded `http://localhost/test/category.php?k=fashion&page=2`. Because of this, you either need to make all your links absolute URLs or add the base in you html header:

```
<base href="/test/" />
```